# How to get documents in a response of Full text search query against Couchbase?

Tags: c#, couchbase

I'm running full text search query against Couchbase, code below.
However, all I get back from database is document IDs and additional information on matched strings. Is there a way to retrieve documents in Full Text Search ?

```
var searchResult = await bucket.QueryAsync(new SearchQuery
{
                    Index = dbConfig.FTS_Index,
                    Query = new BooleanQuery().Must(ftsMust.ToArray()).Should(ftsShould.ToArray()).ShouldMin(0),
                    SearchParams = new SearchParams()
                    .Explain(dbConfig.ExplainResults) 
                    .Highlighting(HighLightStyle.Ansi)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTS index by default just stores the "index" of field, not its original value. If you also want to get this data directly from the index you have also have to specify that in your index config:

[image]

In the case above I have checked the "store" checkbox

You can also automatically store dynamic fields:

[image]

In the image above I have checked the option "Store Dynamic Fields".